# VueJS variable inside URL::action in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am new to VueJS.

I have a link using Laravel Helpers:

```
<a href="{!!   URL::action('TournamentController@edit',  $tournament->id) !!}">{{ $tournament->id }}</a>
```

As it will be inside a VueJS v-for, now I need to refer to Vue variables that I load with AJAX.

So, I tried to write it like that:

```
<a href="{!!   URL::action('TournamentController@edit',  @{{ tournament.id }} ) !!}">@{{ tournament.id }}</a>
```

But I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' (View: /home/vagrant/Code/resources/views/tournaments/index.blade.php)
```

Any Idea how to mix Laravel Helper and VueJS?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you're missing quotes around `@{{ tournament.id }}`.

But after playing around with it myself it doesn't seem possible at the moment due to routes using the same brackets as placeholders.

A workaround would be to create a simple function somewhere that generates the url with a unique placeholder and afterwards you do a `str_replace` call on the generated url.

Answer (score -1):

That's the thing I dislike in the helpers and I have completely stopped using them. IMHO the best way to go is to create a route for that (or a Route::controller) and map those urls to a controller. and then use something like:

```
<a href="{{url('tournament/edit')}}/@{{ tournament.id }}">@{{ tournament.id }}</a>
```

Your routes could be something like:

```
Route::controller('tournament','TournamentController');
```

and your function inside the controller:

```
function getEdit($tournament_id){
   // something something
}
```

And something like this would work

Comment: This could work very well but it kind of assumes the parameter is always at the end of the url `/tournament/edit/1`, this would not work if you'd want a url like this `/tournament/1/edit`. Pretty much all depends on your preference. :)

Comment: also that can be arranjed by setting a default in the function like function edit($id=false) and only pull an article if the id is passed, else maybe redirect to the article list? it's all about architecture and not preference. You should prefer what's logic and what best serve your business logic. if a URL compromises the way you're building an app maybe it's better to rethink your URLs

Comment: So how would you solve this issue when for example the url would be something like this: `/tournaments/1/contestants/edit/1/`?

Comment: I am sure that would exist several solutions. I would make a regexp or a dedicated class to choose action. send everything for one function that would have the responsability to choose the right action. Single responsability principle. One function that has a responsability to choose and each other function would have a specific responsability too. But hey, that would be what I would choose.